# Can Kuldevi give liberation that is moksha?

Tags: moksha, devi

So many deities can as part of the panchdev, Trinity, shakti, suriya dev, Ganesha, Murugan and so. Shakti is one is the case as same for kuldevi/dev? and assist being a guru.

Comment: No one can give you moksha other than Supreme God. See [this](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7/verse/20) and read the commentary.